# How to write file to memory filepath and read from memory filepath in Python?

Tags: python, linux, azure-functions

An existing Python package requires a filepath as input parameter for a method to be able to parse the file from the filepath. I want to use this very specific Python package in a cloud environment, where I can't write files to the harddrive. I don't have direct control over the code in the existing Python package, and it's not easy to switch to another environment, where I would be able to write files to the harddrive. So I'm looking for a solution that is able to write a file to a memory filepath, and let the parser read directly from this memory filepath. Is this possible in Python? Or are there any other solutions?

Example Python code that works by using harddrive, which should be changed so that no harddrive is used:

```
temp_filepath = "./temp.txt"
with open(temp_filepath, "wb") as file:
  file.write("some binary data")
model = Model()
model.parse(temp_filepath)
```

Example Python code that uses memory filesystem to store file, but which does not let parser read file from memory filesystem:

```
from fs import open_fs
temp_filepath = "./temp.txt"
with open_fs('osfs://~/') as home_fs:
  home_fs.writetext(temp_filepath, "some binary data")
model = Model()
model.parse(temp_filepath)
```

Comment: Can this package also accept an open file object? In that case you could use `io.BytesIO`.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using an Azure Function on Linux OS

Comment: The package can't accept an open file object, and it requires the filepath. It even validates if the filepath has the correct extension

Comment: Found a solution by Microsoft to be able to store data on the temporary directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/42218/python-37-file-system-is-read-only.html

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for [`StringIO` or `BytesIO` from `io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

```py
import io

with io.BytesIO() as tmp:
    tmp.write(content)
    # to continue working, rewind file pointer
    tmp.seek(0)
    # work with tmp
```

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) may also be an advantage

Comment: Thanks for the answer ti7. Unfortunately, the package can't accept an open file object such as io.BytesIO or io.StringIO, because the Python package validates the suffix based on the filename and the type of file based on the filepath.